# Configure time period/interval for SonarQube history diagram

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

It looks SonarQube's "History" diagram is always configured for about a two-month period. I'd like to produce a diagram that shows decreasing technical debt for a specific time period that correlates with a certain clean-up initiative? How can I configure the diagram to show a specific time period?

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. Are you referring to a dashboard widget?

Comment: Sorry for the lag; I'm referring to [this](http://imgur.com/sBKZUyj) diagram; yes, I guess it's what one could call a dashboard widget.